# Android Studio not recognising Android device

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently installed Linux Mint on my windows PC as I had heard it is much lighter and faster. I loved it. So I installed android studio on it (which I am currently learning) from the Software Manager but it was an old version. So I download from the Android Developers site and followed the instructions to install. It works fine, but does not identify my Lenovo Tab when I plug it in to debug. Debugging is enabled in the tablet. I tried using different cables and ports but to no prevail.

What should I do? I would be happy to provide any more info if needed

Comment: Android studio doesn't recognize your lenovo tablet means your device driver is not installed properly. So for your tablet debugging you first need to install the tablet device driver.

Comment: @DhavalShah I cannot find any find any drivers for linux. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: This page worth to checkout, https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device as it contains information of setting up android device in linux OS environment. Hope it helps.